# Rails count number of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, count

In Rails 3.1, how can I get a count of the number of attributes an object has?

For instance, I have an object called Projects and I would like to know how many attributes (columns) it has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Project.columns.size
```

[Docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute_names).

Comment: It might be slightly more performant to use `Project.column_names.size`, since `Project.columns` has to instantiate column objects.

Comment: I disagree. It's actually less so. Take a look at how [column_names works](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/36d7af34d6e878a4557ba8a2c282609da2f646ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L247). It just runs a map function on top of `columns`, which makes it pretty much the same as `Project.columns.map(&:name).size`.

Comment: If the author needs to know the actual amount of attributes a model has, he needs `@foo.attributes.size` (`Project.select(:id).first.attributes.size` returns 1 which is much more important to know then the table's columns count).

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfect. I used this to create a % completeness of filled out attributes.